# Quitar comas de un string

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente metodo que me hace lo siguiente:

```
List<String> listaCriterios = new ArrayList<String>();

GroupDTO g = groupService.getCriteriosBusqueda(codIdGrupo);     

List<GroupDTO> list = g.getListGroupSon();
Long filtroAnterior = 0L;
String criterioString = "";

for(GroupDTO u : list){
    if ("0".equals(u.getOpeRegla())) {
        u.setOpeRegla(" != ");
    } else {
        u.setOpeRegla(" = ");
    }

    if(filtroAnterior.equals(u.getFiltroBusqueda()) || filtroAnterior == 0 ){
        criterioString = criterioString + " " + u.getTipoRegla() +  u.getOpeRegla() + u.getRegla() + " , ";
    } else {
        listaCriterios.add(criterioString);
        criterioString = " " + u.getTipoRegla() + u.getOpeRegla() + u.getRegla() + " , ";
    }
    filtroAnterior = u.getFiltroBusqueda();

}
```

Lo que quiero conseguir es que las filas que no tenga mas texto a la derecha se les quite la coma.

Answer (score 1):

De un modo rápido, después de crear el string puedes quitar los dos últimos caracteres

```
criterioString = criterioString.substring(0, criterioString.length() - 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Mi solución:

```
// primero quitamos espacios por si los hubiese (en fin, no sabemos si hay uno, dos o ningún espacio)
criterioString = criterioString.trim();

// ahora a ver si termina en coma (lo que nos interesa)
if (criterioString.endsWith(",")) {
    // sí, termina en coma - substring quitando el último caracter
    criterioString = criterioString.substring(0, criterioString.length() - 1);
}
```

Como dice Raul mas abajo, hay que explicar como se llega la solución. Pues básicamente programando 20 años en java, pero al margen de eso, es una cosa bastante simple y cualquiera podría llegar a la solución. Pongo unos comentarios en el código.

Comment: Para que sea mejor recibida la respuesta explica como llegaste a la solución